# How to clear the session in IBM Mobilefirst Platform Foundation 7.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing an application using Adapter-based authentication.

We have observed that after user1 logs out, and user2 logs in we are getting an error such as: "user already exist, please logout".

To resolve this issue we need to clear the MobileFirst Server session, when the user2 tries to login.

what are the ways to clear  the MobileFirst Server session

**Application Config.xml**

```
 <staticResources>

    <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>

</staticResources>    

 <securityTests>

    <mobileSecurityTest name="PushApplications">
        <testUser realm="pushAppRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>           

</securityTests> 

<realms>
    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
    </realm>

    <realm loginModule="PushAppLoginModule" name="pushAppRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="pushNotificationAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="pushNotificationAdapter.onLogout"/>
    </realm>

</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="rejectAll" expirationInSeconds="3600">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>


    <loginModule name="PushAppLoginModule" >
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>  
</loginModules>
```

**Appliation Descriptor.xml**

```
<displayName>pushNotification</displayName>
<description>pushNotification</description>
<author>
    <name>application's author</name>
    <email>application author's e-mail</email>
    <homepage>http://mycompany.com</homepage>
    <copyright>Copyright My Company</copyright>
</author>
<mainFile>index.html</mainFile>
<features/>
<targetCategory>UNDEFINED</targetCategory>
<licenseAppType>APPLICATION</licenseAppType>
<thumbnailImage>common/images/thumbnail.png</thumbnailImage>
<userIdentityRealms>pushAppRealm</userIdentityRealms>
<accessTokenExpiration>3600</accessTokenExpiration>
<android version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
     <pushSender key="AIzaSyAxazrxBZ1tDQWhuGRsQR3DLiPzfm-O-V8" senderId="1019918790021"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey/>
        <packageName/>
    </security>
</android>
```

**when user click on login button**

```js
function wlCommonInit() {

  WL.Client.connect({
   onSuccess : onConnectSuccess,
   onFailure : onConnectFailure
  });

  function onConnectSuccess() {
   alert(WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPushh"))
  }
  function onConnectFailure() {
   alert("connection failed")
  }
  
 }

$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmitLogin', function () {
 var civilId=document.getElementById("txtMbrIdLogin").value;
 
 if(WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("pushAppRealm")==false){
  if(WL.Client.getUserName("pushAppRealm")== null){
  alert("user not authenticated");
  if(WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPushh")){
   alert("user subscribed");
        WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPushh", {
              onSuccess: function() {
               alert("unsubscribe success");
               callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
              },
              onFailure: function() {
               alert("unsubscribe fail")
               callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
              }
          });
       }
  else{
   alert("user not subscribed");
   callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
  }
  }else{
   WL.Client.logout('pushAppRealm', { onSuccess: function() {
             alert("logout"); if(WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPushh")){
         alert("user subscribed");
          WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPushh", {
                onSuccess: function() {
                 callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
                },
                onFailure: function() {
                 alert("unsubscribe fail")
                 callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
                }
            });
         }else{
   callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
  } }, onFailure:function() {
               alert("Unable to logout");
             } });
            // callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM"); 
  }
  }
  else if(WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("pushAppRealm")==true){
   if(WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPushh")){
         WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPushh", {
               onSuccess: function() {
                  WL.Client.logout('pushAppRealm', { onSuccess: function() {
                      alert("logout");  callSubmitAuthentication();
                    }, onFailure:function() {
                        alert("Unable to logout");
                    }});
                callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
               },
               onFailure: function() {
                callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
               }
           });
        }else{
     callSubmitAuthentication(civilId,"from QLM");
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: If you are using Logout API you should see this problem. Are you actually logging out using Logout API?

Comment: Yes we are using Logout API

Comment: Can you try WL.Server.setActiveUser("realmname",null); before doing WL.Server.setActiveUser("realmname",username)?

Comment: if we doing that WL.Server.setActiveUser("realmname",username) is looping.

Comment: Provide a recreatable sample

Comment: Try [`WL.Client.logout("realmName")`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#logout).

Comment: Are you using MFPF 7.1 in session-dependent mode or session-independent mode?

Comment: Yes, we are using MFPF7.1 in session-independent mode

Comment: Are you testing in the browser or on a device?

Comment: Also please provide your full MobileFirst version number (with timestamp).

Comment: we are testing in device and MFPF version is 7.1.0.00-20160323-1606

Comment: Please update your original question with code snippets for the challenge handlers, adapters, authentication config, etc. Also add any information you provided in the comments here.

Comment: Vivin and Nathan,this is my sample code link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z3xUUwcxaLODVDN0FHRHJvRms/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer for your specific scenario, but I can say that the code sample you provided makes no sense and it should not be expected to work.

For example:

```
pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
    if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }
     if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
            if(response.responseJSON.authRequired == false){
            pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();
            }
     }else{
         return false;
     }

}
```

If the framework calls `handleChallenge`, you are **required** to answer the challenge. Whether by sending credentials back to the server, submitFailure or submitSuccess. Returning `true` or `false` is not an option. This method does not have a return value, it is supposed to **collect credentials and send them to the server**.

You also have a line in the middle of nowhere: `pushAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData,{});`.

It's sending invalid credentials to the server every time you load the file.

I will stop here, but so far nothing in this sample makes sense or is expected to work.

Take baby steps. Please go back to the basics, study the simplest samples, read **all** the tutorials. Test your flow after each baby step. If you have questions about a specific issue we're here to help.

Also, I can also recommend trying MobileFirst Platform v8.0